# reshape csv file in R

Tags: r

If I have a big tab-delimited file like this,

```
lowenbrau
a 789
b 678
c 970
augustiner
d 89
e 563
f 456
g 123
```

and so on, and I want to add a column with the title like this,

```
a 789 lowenbrau
b 678 lowenbrau
c 970 lowenbrau
d 89 augustiner
e 563 augustiner
f 456 augustiner
g 123 augustiner
```

What function or package should I use in R?
I apologize for not providing my try, but sincerely I don't know how to search this problem to have a hint. So any hint is welcome.

Comment: Install [the SOfun package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun) and use `read.mtable("yourfile", "^[a-z]+$", ...)`. Fill in `...` with other arguments you would normally use with `read.table`. Then you can use `rbindlist(the_result, idcol=TRUE)` from "data.table" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the file with `readLines`, create a logical index, `split` into `list`, then `stack` it to `data.frame` and split the first column into two columns with `read.table`

```
i1 <- grepl("^\\w+$", lines)
d1 <- stack(setNames(split(lines[!i1], cumsum(i1)[!i1]), lines[i1]))
cbind(read.table(text=d1$values, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), d1[2])
#  V1  V2        ind
#1  a 789  lowenbrau
#2  b 678  lowenbrau
#3  c 970  lowenbrau
#4  d  89 augustiner
#5  e 563 augustiner
#6  f 456 augustiner
#7  g 123 augustiner
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("file.txt")
```

Comment: thank you akrun, what does this mean "^\\w+$"? it is not working with my actual data, and I think the problem might be here.

Comment: @user3224522  Because you showed only pattern with a single word i.e. 'lowenbrau' and 'augstiner' I thought there might be only a single word in the whole document. `^` start and `$` end of the string that separates the other lines.  Can you try with `"^[A-Za-z]+$"` (as  A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 showed in the comments)?